# How to delete a polyline in Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, polyline

I can do it in Google Maps by using

```
polyline.map = nil
```

and

```
mapView.clear()
```

but I cannot find any relevant methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `mapView.removeAnnotation(polyline)`

Where `mapView` is your `MGLMapView` and `polyline` is a `MGLPolyline`.

You will probably need to keep track of your polylines, how you do that is up to you (array, dictionary, etc)

[Here is the documentation for MGLMapView if you need it](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#//api/name/removeAnnotation:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a category extension method for `MGLMapView` that I am using.
Its just like `Google Maps SDK`, so its easier to use anywhere in your project.

```
- (void)clear {
    if (self.annotations.count > 0) {
        NSArray *annotations = self.annotations;
        [self removeAnnotations:annotations];
    }
}
```

You can use it like

```
[self.mapView clear];
```